# How to compare two hashmaps in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two hash maps like the following:

```
1.=============Employee=================


Key : 1_10 : Value : 13/04/2012
Key : 1_11 : Value : 18/04/2012
Key : 1_12 : Value : 19/04/2012
Key : 1_14 : Value : 23/04/2012
Key : 1_13 : Value : 20/04/2012
Key : 1_16 : Value : 25/04/2012
Key : 1_1  : Value : 02/04/2012
Key : 1_15 : Value : 24/04/2012
Key : 1_18 : Value : 27/04/2012
Key : 1_3  : Value : 04/04/2012
Key : 1_17 : Value : 26/04/2012
Key : 1_2  : Value : 03/04/2012
Key : 1_5  : Value : 06/04/2012
Key : 1_19 : Value : 30/04/2012
Key : 1_4  : Value : 05/04/2012
Key : 1_7  : Value : 10/04/2012
Key : 1_6  : Value : 09/04/2012
Key : 1_9  : Value : 12/04/2012
Key : 1_8  : Value : 11/04/2012

2.=============Working day=================

Key : 27 : Value : 27/4/2012
Key : 02 : Value : 02/4/2012
Key : 26 : Value : 26/4/2012
Key : 19 : Value : 19/4/2012
Key : 11 : Value : 11/4/2012
Key : 04 : Value : 04/4/2012
Key : 30 : Value : 30/4/2012
Key : 06 : Value : 06/4/2012
Key : 13 : Value : 13/4/2012
Key : 09 : Value : 09/4/2012
Key : 03 : Value : 03/4/2012
Key : 23 : Value : 23/4/2012
Key : 20 : Value : 20/4/2012
Key : 16 : Value : 16/4/2012
Key : 10 : Value : 10/4/2012
Key : 18 : Value : 18/4/2012
Key : 25 : Value : 25/4/2012
Key : 17 : Value : 17/4/2012
Key : 12 : Value : 12/4/2012
Key : 24 : Value : 24/4/2012
Key : 05 : Value : 05/4/2012
```

Keys are not same but the values are same and sometime the values are not same.

i want to find out the value which are not present in `employeemap` when  comparing with `workingdaymap`

```java
if (!employeeMap.containsValue(workingdayMap.get(wKey))) {
    //take the value which is not present in employeeMap which is present in workingdayMap
}
```

but it gives me null from employeeMap.

Could you please help me to solve this?

Regards
Tony

Comment: Check out `values()` function of `HashMap`.

Comment: Could you provide more of the code that gives you `null`?  Where does `wKey` come from?  Which date type are you using, and does its `equals()` method do what you think it does?

Comment: Iterator<String> workingDayIterator = workingdayMap.keySet().iterator();
           while(workingDayIterator.hasNext()){
            String wKey= workingDayIterator.next();
            
            if(!employeeMap.containsValue(workingdayMap.get(wKey))){
             // get the values
              }
            
           }

Comment: Okay, that code looks good.  What do you mean by "it gives you null"?  Is there an exception?  Can we get the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the code which works perfectly, the reason why the comparison failed is the map value is different .

```
Key : 27 : Value : 27/4/2012, Key : 1_18 : Value : 27/04/2012
```

if we see the dates, the difference is clearly seen.  `27/4/2012` is different from  `27/04/2012` since i stored it as a string.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> holyDayiterator = workingdayMap.entrySet().iterator();
                 
                 while (holyDayiterator.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry holiDayEntry = holyDayiterator.next();
                    if(!employeeMap.containsValue((holiDayEntry.getValue()))){
                        System.out.println("works perfect");
                    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are the Values Date objects? If so you're attempting to see if the map contains the same object (well its hash, which will be different unless you stored the EXACT same instance in both maps) rather than the value of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
Set workingValues = new HashSet(workingdayMap.values());
workingValues.removeAll(employeeMap.values());
```

We get all the values out of `workingdayMap` using the `values()` method.  We don't want to modify this `Collection` directly as this will modify `workingdayMap` so we create a `Set` of our values called `workingValues`.

We then remove all the values found in `employeeMap` which will leave the values which are in `workingdayMap` but not in `employeeMap` in `workingValues`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try like this.

```
    HashMap<String, Date> employeeMap = new HashMap<String, Date>();

    HashMap<String, Date> workingdaymap = new HashMap<String, Date>();

    Set<String> values1 = new HashSet<String>(employeeMap.values());
    Set<String> values2 = new HashSet<String>(workingdaymap.values());
    boolean equal = values1.equals(value2);
```