# How to compare two hasmaps in java irrespective of their keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare two hashmaps in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813196/how-to-compare-two-hashmaps-in-java)

Hi i have two different has maps which has got values like the following

Map,

```
1.=============Employee=================


Key : 1_10 : Value : 13/04/2012
Key : 1_11 : Value : 18/04/2012
Key : 1_12 : Value : 19/04/2012
Key : 1_14 : Value : 23/04/2012
Key : 1_13 : Value : 20/04/2012
Key : 1_16 : Value : 25/04/2012
Key : 1_1  : Value : 02/04/2012
Key : 1_15 : Value : 24/04/2012
Key : 1_18 : Value : 27/04/2012
Key : 1_3  : Value : 04/04/2012
Key : 1_17 : Value : 26/04/2012
Key : 1_2  : Value : 03/04/2012
Key : 1_5  : Value : 06/04/2012
Key : 1_19 : Value : 30/04/2012
Key : 1_4  : Value : 05/04/2012
Key : 1_7  : Value : 10/04/2012
Key : 1_6  : Value : 09/04/2012
Key : 1_9  : Value : 12/04/2012
Key : 1_8  : Value : 11/04/2012

2.=============Working day=================

Key : 27 : Value : 27/4/2012
Key : 02 : Value : 02/4/2012
Key : 26 : Value : 26/4/2012
Key : 19 : Value : 19/4/2012
Key : 11 : Value : 11/4/2012
Key : 04 : Value : 04/4/2012
Key : 30 : Value : 30/4/2012
Key : 06 : Value : 06/4/2012
Key : 13 : Value : 13/4/2012
Key : 09 : Value : 09/4/2012
Key : 03 : Value : 03/4/2012
Key : 23 : Value : 23/4/2012
Key : 20 : Value : 20/4/2012
Key : 16 : Value : 16/4/2012
Key : 10 : Value : 10/4/2012
Key : 18 : Value : 18/4/2012
Key : 25 : Value : 25/4/2012
Key : 17 : Value : 17/4/2012
Key : 12 : Value : 12/4/2012
Key : 24 : Value : 24/4/2012
Key : 05 : Value : 05/4/2012
```

I just want to compare these two hash maps and give values which are not present in maps over the other one.

Comment: This answer should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10813470/1400768

Comment: it was not helpful so that i changed question and asked

Comment: @Tony How is that not helpful? Also, don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: @Tony You will likely get the same answer. Why don't you try to make it work and if you can't, come back **with code** that does not do what you expect?

Comment: You got three answers and didn't leave a single comment on any. You just abandoned the question and re-asked. That kind of behavior isn't just frowned-upon here, it's actually making people angry at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose map1 is hashmap of your 1st map and map2 is hashmap of your 2nd map. Then,

```
Collection<String> c1 = map1.values();
c1.removeAll(map2.values());  // this one removes all the values from c1 which are also in map2.
Iterator<String> it = c1.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

hence you get the values which map1 contains which map2 does not contain.

Comment: That's a lot of characters to just iterate over a collection; we're in the future and use foreach now.

Comment: I didn't have a problem, other than with the formatting, and the extra verbosity.

Comment: @DaveNewton,@JackAss, the above solution gives no exception but it does not remove which map1 contains which map2 does not contain. thanks guys for your effort, i had to solve this issue so that i have asked twice changing the question to make understandable not to make anybody angry. I also know that this is the place where i get exact answer and get connected with good people like you guys. I am sorry if my question made you guys to get irritated. Tony