# how to fill a char array with a given string

Tags: java, char, arrays

Here is my code where i read a txt file and create 2 string from its content now i need to create 2 char array with these 2 strings. How can i do this?

```
java.io.File file=new java.io.File("deneme3.txt");
    try{
        Scanner input=new Scanner(file);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String num= input.nextLine();
            String[] parts =num.split(" ");
            String part1=parts[0];
            String part2=parts[1];
```

in the end i need to have something like;

`char[] mSeqA` and `char[] mSeqB`;

Comment: `String` objects have a method `toCharArray()`. Just read the doc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: This is not a question any more.

Comment: @judge: Please stop defacing your questions once they have been answered! Just let them be.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare two hashmaps in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813196/how-to-compare-two-hashmaps-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char[] mSeqA=parts[0].toCharArray();
char[] mSeqB=parts[1].toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to a char array you can simply write

```
String str = "someString"; 
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

So in your case it would be

```
char[] mSeqA = parts[0].toCharArray();
char[] mSeqB = parts[1].toCharArray();
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html for details